# Form not hiding on submit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Upon submit, the form (`#register_form`) should be hidden. Currently it is not doing that, no console errors. Am I missing something?

The form is inline. The submission process happens on the same page.

```js
$("#register_form").submit(function(e) {
  $(".client_hide").hide();
  $("#post_text").show();
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" class="client_hide form-horizontal" action="client3.php" id="register_form">
  <div class="button">
    <button type="submit" name="register_submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Form is a link, it navigates to client3.php.

Comment: What does "client3.php" return? When you submit the form, the page will be re-drawn with whatever the server returns.

Comment: By default a form navigates to a new page.  (Which may be the same URL, but that doesn't matter.)  There's no code here which would prevent that from happening.  *Is this* form submitting and loading a new page?  If so, any changes made to the previous page would of course be lost.

Comment: @David the Form submission code is inline so its reload itself?

Comment: Did you mean to call `e.preventDefault()` and make an outgoing AJAX call to the server instead?

Comment: Form loads whatever is responded from client3.php in your case, which is the value of `action` attribute.

Comment: @acctman: So then, yes, if the form is submitting and a new page is being loaded then any changes made to the previous page are lost.  If you want to customize the new page then you'll likely want to do that in your server-side code in `client3.php`.  It sounds like overall you're somewhat misunderstanding how web pages work in general.  You can prevent the form submission and keep the user on the same page, or you can submit the form and navigate the user to a new page (even if it's the "same page" again).  If the latter, *that* page would need whatever customizations you want to see.

Comment: Please revise the demo above to show the problem. If the page is indeed refreshing due to backend submission, that's a different question.